# printing format string function and variable (python)

Tags: python, string, printing, tuples, formatted

definition of function & variable:

```
def secret_formula(started):
    jelly_beans = started * 500
    jars = jelly_beans / 1000
    crates = jars / 100
    return jelly_beans, jars, crates

start_point = 10000 / 10
```

print statement:

```
print """crazy different style:
startpoint: %d\n
beans:\t\t %d\n
jars:\t\t %d\n
crates:\t\t %d\n
""" % (start_point, (secret_formula(start_point)))
```

The error message I get is " %d format: a number is required, not a tuple.
Please help me fix it. I´m really new to programming...or is it just not possible to pack a variable and a called function into the same formattet print?

Comment: you have the solution right there in your problem statement. `" %d format: a number is required, not a tuple`.also see about python `string formatting`.if you are new to programming work up on your basics. any decent tutorial/site about python will have thing you want to understand about basic constructs of python.

Comment: It seems like you want to unpack your tuple `(secret_formula(start_point))` into several arguments. You can do that with the unpacking operator; i.e. `*(secret_formula(start_point))`

Answer (score 0):

a variant for in python 2:

```
print """crazy different style:
startpoint: %d\n
beans:\t\t %d\n
jars:\t\t %d\n
crates:\t\t %d\n
""" % ((start_point, ) + secret_formula(start_point))
```

where i create a new tuple by adding the tuple `(start_point, )` to the result of your function.

---

in python 3 you can [unpack the tuple with a `*`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments):

```
print("""crazy different style:
startpoint: %d\n
beans:\t\t %d\n
jars:\t\t %d\n
crates:\t\t %d\n
""" % (start_point, *secret_formula(start_point)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding `*` in order to unpack the tuple (python 3.x solution):

```
print ("""crazy different style:
startpoint: %d\n
beans:\t\t %d\n
jars:\t\t %d\n
crates:\t\t %d\n
""" % (start_point, *(secret_formula(start_point))))
```

If you're using python 2.x can type:

```
start_point = 10000 / 10
res = secret_formula(start_point)
print """crazy different style:
startpoint: %d\n
beans:\t\t %d\n
jars:\t\t %d\n
crates:\t\t %d\n
""" % (start_point, res[0], res[1], res[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#According to zen of python Explicit is better than implicit, so

bs, js, cs = secret_formula(start_point)

print """crazy different style:
startpoint: %d\n
beans:\t\t %d\n
jars:\t\t %d\n
crates:\t\t %d\n
""" % (start_point, bs, js, cs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Working on python 3

```
def secret_formula(started):
    jelly_beans = started * 500
    jars = jelly_beans / 1000
    crates = jars / 100
    return jelly_beans, jars, crates

start_point = 10000 / 10

print ("startpoint : {0} \n \
       beans:\t\t {1}  \n \
       jar :\t\t {2}".format(start_point,*secret_formula(start_point)[:2]))
```

output

```
startpoint : 1000.0 
    beans:       500000.0  
    jar :        500.0
```